# Show Delete Button On Right Side Of Bootstrap Row, On Hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I saw a lot of examples of popping up a delete button over a container.  I want to show over a Twitter Bootstrap row, on the right side of the row.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
       Content
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
       Content
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
       Content
   </div>
</div>
```

A lot of the samples involved using a relative position on the container; however, I don't want to mess with the existing table display on the .row, so is there a better way of doing that on popup for a twitter bootstrap row?

EDIT: I'd like to show a button on the right, centered in the row.  A button with the following markup:

```
<button ..><i class="icon-remove-sign"></i></button>
```

Which shows only on hover.

Comment: Could you give an example what exactly you want to achieve? I don't really understand what you want.

Comment: I want to show a button on the right side to offer a delete option, when you hover over the row.

Comment: Like this? http://www.bootply.com/jy0it9mhr2

Comment: Yes!  That would do it, thanks much.  I was surprised to not be able to find anything online, that's exactly what I need.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
       Content
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
       Content
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
       Content
   </div>
   <div class="hover-btn">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
     </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    position: relative;
  }

  .hover-btn {
     position: absolute;
     right: 15px;
     display: none;
  }

  .row:hover .hover-btn {
     display: block;
  }
```

[**Working Example**](http://www.bootply.com/jy0it9mhr2)

Comment: Is there any drawbacks to using CSS to  position the row relatively?

Comment: None that I could think of. Since the default position `static` isn't much different than `relative`. You can read more about it here: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/